Can you use hoarse to describe anything other than a voice?
TOEFL reading question.
The sentence on line 12 reads:

The bottom of an osprey‘s toes are very rough because of the small
wart-like ridges called spicules that give the bird a surer grasp for
fish catching.

The question:

The word "rough" in line 12 refers to _______.
(A) sharp
(B) steep
(C) curved
(D) hoarse

The answer key says it's hoarse.
Is there a way to use hoarse for anything other than a voice?
My initial answer was curved. It's still incorrect, but I figured it was the best option I had.

"Hoarse" is simply the wrong answer - although it can be used of sounds other than that of the human voice. It's a strange question because the word "rough" doesn't really refer to any of the options given. "Curved" makes most sense because we know that the bird's claws are curved but that's not what rough means.

That's a mistake in the answer book. Maybe they mean which one doesn't fit at all, and not that hoarse is correct.

I’m voting to close this question because there is a mistake in the book.

Probably a typo for coarse.

It's potentially confusing because rough ("having an uneven surface") can be applied literally to the bottom of an osprey‘s toes, or metaphorically to sounds (especially, voices) that we label hoarse. But the metaphoric transference doesn't work in the opposite direction - literal hoarse (husky, croaky, raucous) can't be metaphorically applied to a rough surface.

Short answer - no, not really.
The etymology of 'hoarse' in connection with the throat or voice seems to come from words relating to being "dry", and "like a husk" (the dry outer coating of seeds), hence the related term "husky". It seems to have been uniquely applied to the voice to describe the sound.
It is possible that your book has confused this for the word 'coarse', which means rough or harsh in texture.
